# Cannot access directories over SMB (permissions error)

Tags: macos, permission, big-sur, smb

I am unable to access directories like `~/Documents`, `~/Downloads`, or `~/Desktop` via SMB — the SB share on which they exist can be accessed, but not the directories themselves (trying to browse them gives permissions errors)

In Console.app, I have (for `kernel`), e.g.,

```
System Policy: smbd(7706) deny(1) file-read-data /Users/alex/Documents
```

This appears when I try to access `~/Documents`.

How can I fix this so `~/Documents` and similar dirs are accessible via SMB?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the **Privacy** tab of the **Security & Privacy** system preference pane, make sure that either:

1. `smbd` appears and is checked in the **Full Disk Access** list, or
2. `smbd` appears with `Documents Folder` checked below it in the **Files and Folders** list.

If you need to add `smbd`, it can be found in `/usr/sbin`.

Comment: Agh, this feels so obvious now! Thanks for the clear answer.